# How to replace front fog light housing on a Corsa C 2005

Tags: replace, lights, vauxhall, corsa

I need to replace my front fog light housing before my MOT as it's completely ruined.

What is the best way to do this?

DO I need to take the entire bumper off?

***The image below is what I'm replacing***

[image]

Comment: You're just talking about the bulb, right?

Comment: No essentially the whole housing as it's cracked and the lens is smashed (previous owner)

Comment: Is the unit in the photograph upside down? I found this online manual, it looks similar but the other way up?

Comment: Which online manual? It may be, it's not my photo

Comment: http://workshop-manuals.com/vauxhall/corsa-c/n__electrical_equipment_and_instruments/headlamps_lamps_and_horn/fog_lamp/repair_instructions/front_fog_lamp/bulb_replace/

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add the link. It looks like there are three screws to remove from the back of the unit and the fascia unclips from the bumper and is pulled out from the front.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*EDIT: I have heard that you do not need to remove the entire wing panelling. I certainly didn't on my 2003 Opel Agila. Just remove the screws from the front of the wing on the bottom of the car. Makes life easier.* **YOUR MILAGE MAY VARY ON THE CORSA!**

This is what Vauxhall has to say about the front fog lights.

Firstly, we need to remove the inner paneling (basically the bumper):

1. Release left and right front wheel cut-out panel

   - Unscrew 4x nuts (1)
   - Pull out wheel cut-out panel slightly and fix in place

[image]

[image]

2. Undo front panelling at top

   - Unscrew 3x bolt (2)
3. Release left and right wing protective liner

   - Unscrew 4x bolts (1) and (3)
4. Undo front panelling at bottom

   - Remove 3x body-bound rivets (4)
5. Remove front panelling

   - Release panelling from guide rail at the side

     Note:  This requires a second person

---

Now back to removing the lamps:

[image]

2. Remove front fog lamp

   -Unscrew 3x bolt (arrows)

   -Release front fog light wiring harness plug and disconnect
3. Remove cover to change bulb (1)

   - Disconnect wiring harness plug
   - Unlock retaining spring (2) and remove bulb

---

Reinstalling:

Replace bulb:

```
   - Insert bulb, lock retaining spring

   - Connect wiring harness plug

   - Attach cover
```

5. Attach front fog lamp

   - Tighten 3x bolt
   - Connect wiring harness plug
6. Put on front panelling

   - Clip panelling into guide rail

     Note:  This requires a second person
7. Fasten front panelling at bottom

   - Install 3x body-bound rivets
8. Attach left and right wing protective liner

   - Tighten 4x bolt
9. Fasten front panelling at top

   - Tighten 3x bolts
10. Fasten left and right front wheel cut-out panel

    - Tighten 4x nuts

---

Adjusting the fog lamps

[image]

Tyre pressure, Test and Adjust Adjustment is performed at vehicle curb weight plus one person or 75 kg on the driver seat. See also operation "Headlamps, Test and Adjust".

Adjust fog lamp with adjusting screw (1) to upper light-dark boundary line with adjuster. The light-dark boundary line is horizontal along the adjusting line.

The inclination of the front fog lamps is 20 cm at 10 m (corresponds to a light beam inclination of 2 %).

Answer (score 3):

*Note: I've never replaced this part on this vehicle.*

- Raise the front of the car.
- Look under the front bumper area.
- Is it uncovered? Can you access the fog light assemblies?
- If yes: simply remove the bolts holding them and pull them out carefully.
- If not: you have to pull the front bumper cover.

  I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yI2EfoZXKm8) that shows how to remove the bumper. Its a very simple procedure that you can do with common hand tools.